# Entry box moving when Scrolling on Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, datatemplate

So, i am based on this example of DataTemplate [Monkey Chat using DataTemplate](https://github.com/markradacz/Xamarin.Forms-Samples/tree/master/DataTemplateSelector)

According to this i applie to my case but i am with a big problem. When Scroll, the Entry Disappear because are going together. I tried to put StackLayout but no success. I Don´t know how make this work correct. If someone know, please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="DataTemplateSelector.MainPage"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataTemplateSelector;assembly=DataTemplateSelector">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MessageTemplateSelector"></local:MyDataTemplateSelector>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
 <ScrollView>
        <ContentPage.Content>
  <RelativeLayout>
  <ListView x:Name="MessagesListView" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
            HasUnevenRows="True" 
            ItemSelected="MyListView_OnItemSelected"
            ItemTapped="MyListView_OnItemTapped"
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}">
   </ListView>
    <Grid x:Name="MessageControls" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="2" Padding="5"
          BackgroundColor="#EFEFF4"
          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=MessagesListView, Property=Height,Factor=.91,Constant=0}"
          RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
          RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=MessagesListView, Property=Height,Factor=.09,Constant=0}">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Entry Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="25" Placeholder="Message" Text="{Binding OutGoingText}"></Entry>
      <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Send" Command="{Binding SendCommand}"></Button>
    </Grid>

  </RelativeLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem? The xaml codes you posted are almost identical to the sample that works.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Wich sample Works ? Because the sample of the website that i posted is the same and has this problem.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT What i need to know is how fix the Entry and Button...i tried to put inside a stacklayout but no Works.